# How to disable umbraco cache

Tags: c#, umbraco

My content editors are complaining because the content they edit is not being updated immediatly in the browser and it's making their job hard.

I have tried the following in umbracosettings.config to no avail:

```
<settings>
    <content>
        <XmlContentCheckForDiskChanges>true</XmlContentCheckForDiskChanges>
        <ContinouslyUpdateXmlDiskCache>True</ContinouslyUpdateXmlDiskCache>
```

What options do i have?

**Notes:**

- This site is published on Azure hosting
- I make calls from my controllers that traverse nodes like this:

  ```
  public class HomePageController : RenderMvcController
  {
      private IServices services;

      public HomePageController(IServices services)
      {
          this.services = services;
      }

      public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
      {
          var viewModel = this.services.PageService.GetByID(CurrentPage.Id),
          //
          return View("~/Views/MVC/Page/Home.cshtml", viewModel);
      }
  ```
- and the traversing within the services on root node:

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// The root node is required in getting content by document type.
  /// </summary>
  protected IPublishedContent RootNode {
      get
      {
          if( this.contentRootNode == null )
          {
              this.contentRootNode = this.umbracoHelper.TypedContentAtRoot().First();
          }

          return this.contentRootNode;
      }
  }

  protected IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> GetPublishedContent(string documentTypeAlias)
  {
      IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> publishedContent = this.RootNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == documentTypeAlias);

      return publishedContent;
  }
  ```

Comment: Have you checked whether the issue happens on a local computer? Umbraco cache is rebuilt or refreshed on publish. I suspect that it might be an issue with Azure.

Comment: Would <XmlCacheEnabled>False</XmlCacheEnabled> solve the issue? Anything i should be aware of when turning this off?

Comment: That should disable the cache. You might give it a go, although not recommended. Read here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/config/umbracosettings/

Comment: Is it possible you have a Http Cache header set that the Content Editor's web browser is adhering to and caching the content more aggressively? There are browser plugins that can force a clear of the cache client side: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en.